# problem with UISlider : printing values of the slider and getting to change the style

Tags: ios, uislider

I am facing some problem with UISlider programming.

1) style: I know we have to set the minimum and maximum images. I am just not sure what images and any image reference will be great ? I only want to change from blue to black !

2) also, my code for the UISlider is this :

in header file:

```
UISlider *slider;
```

in code file:

```
 //slider
 CGRect frame=CGRectMake(10, 70, 300, 10);
 photoSlider=[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
 photoSlider.minimumValue=0.0;
 photoSlider.maximumValue=90.0; //maximumPhotoImage
 photoSlider.continuous=NO;
 photoSlider.value=10.0;
 photoSlider.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 //photoSlider

 [photoSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(updateImage:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self.view addSubview:photoSlider];

- (void) updateImage:(id) sender  
{
   NSLog(@"val: %d",photoSlider.value);
}
```

The values that I get from the function are 0 at both ends and very large value in between (both positive and negative...random values).

Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part 1, to replace the default blue part of the slider track with black, you could take a snapshot of the default blue track and convert it to a darker grayscale like this (only need the left end and 1 pixel of the stretchable part):
[image]
and call `setMinimumTrackImage:forState:`:

```
UIImage *minTrackImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"MinimumTrackImage.png"] 
    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:4 topCapHeight:0];
[photoSlider setMinimumTrackImage:minTrackImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For part 2, the values logged don't make sense because the `value` property is of type `float` and you need to use `%f` instead of `%d` (see [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)):

```
NSLog(@"val: %f",photoSlider.value);
```

Comment: thanks for part 2. as for part 1 can you tell me if what i understand is correct or not ? idea for part 1 : I need two photos , 1)where the slider is at the beginning and 2) where the slider is at the end. And I also need a picture to change the slider. Right ? Please let me know. Also, is there any specific requirement for the resolution of the pictures ? any links to picures ? thanks :)

Comment: You must have figured it out but for the slider (track) you can specify an image for the left (minimum side) and the right (maximum side).  The images are automatically stretched horizontally as the thumb moves.  The rounded part on the end of the image isn't stretched because we say it is part of the "end cap width".